# libgdx how to split the screen to 4 parts

Tags: java, libgdx, viewport, scene2d, viewport3d

This is how I want my screen to look like:
[image: main screen]
In the left up corner I need to have 6 `3d models` So I will do that using the `PerspectiveCamera`. the right up corner jest need to present some data so I will do that using the `scene2d`. The bottom left corner need a combination when the `3d models` will be drown with a `batch.dra()` and the `PerspectiveCamera` and the data about the models will be a `scene2d`. In the right bottom I jest need a `scene2d` `table` to show all the connected users. My question is how do I split my screen to 4 so every part of the screen will be rendered differently.

Comment: You can use a table with 2 rows and 2 columns. set them to `.expand()` / `.fill()' and they should stretch out equally over the screen. Or calculate it yourself.

Comment: @Madmenyo the problem is that in the left up corner it's not a `scene2d` so I don't want a table cell there.

Comment: Try offsetting the viewport with `setScreenX` `setScreenY` and `screenBounds`. https://libgdx.badlogicgames.com/nightlies/docs/api/com/badlogic/gdx/utils/viewport/Viewport.html

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can try [offsetting the viewport](https://libgdx.badlogicgames.com/nightlies/docs/api/com/badlogic/gdx/utils/viewport/Viewport.html) with `setScreenX`, `setScreenY` and `screenBounds`. You do need to use 2 viewports now.

Otherwise it is possible to alter the viewport directly. `Gdx.gl.glViewport( 0,Gdx.graphics.getHeight() / 2,Gdx.graphics.getWidth()/2,Gdx.graphics.getHeight() / 2 );` should draw everything in the upper corner. In update it will look like this:

```
`Gdx.gl.glViewport( 0,Gdx.graphics.getHeight() / 2,Gdx.graphics.getWidth()/2,Gdx.graphics.getHeight() / 2 );
//Draw upper right window stuff

Gdx.gl.glViewport( 0,0, Gdx.graphics.getWidth(),Gdx.graphics.getHeight());
//Draw your stage and just leave the upper right window/table cell transparent
```

I didn't test out either solution so I'm not sure if it will work for you.

Comment: I saw this solution as well. But the problem is that I am currently using fit view port and with this solution is that the ratio dose not save. Things start stretch.

Comment: Obviously you need to set the width and height with the correct aspect ratio. I'm not sure what the behaviour is with `FitViewport` and the 2nd method but perhaps you can try `CustomViewport`. The 2nd method should just shrinks everything down to 1/4 of the screen and pushes it to the top left.